# Using images with Skulpt Turtle

Tags: javascript, turtle-graphics, skulpt

When using [Skulpt](http://skulpt.org), how do I access a gif image on the web server? I am using turtle graphics, and I want to set the shape of the turtle to a picture that is saved on the web server, however I'm not sure how to do this.

I know that to do this via a regular python shell, I would just say screen.addshape, and then turtle.shape, however this doesn't work with Skulpt.

What do I do to make it possible to change the shape of a turtle to a gif within Skulpt?

Thanks for any help!